# Windows 10 & Windows Explorer issue

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I quote the following of Scott, on a thread about Windows 7,  just to be more clearer about what I am searching for.
[How to edit the attributes/data of the various columns in windows explorer details view](https://superuser.com/questions/897477/how-to-edit-the-attributes-data-of-the-various-columns-in-windows-explorer-details)

Scott says:

> In Windows Explorer, you can change many column values (data attributes) in the panel below the details area.  The fields that are available for change depend on the file type.  JPEG makes quite a few available:

It drives me crazy searching for this options in my File Explorer on Windows 10.
Is it just me or is it a missing thing ? I want this option back !

Please give me a solution, if possible. I have searched hours long in the IT with no result.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems to me that you're looking to get Windows to show additional metadata about certain filetypes (jpeg, mp3, etc.) so you can maybe sort files according to that data? If you're looking to edit the metadata directly within Explorer (e.g. changing the Album Artist of an MP3 file), I believe only a few attributes for a couple of media file formats are supported.

Answer (score 1):

The details pane has been moved from the bottom in Win10 (or Win8, not sure), and now it resides on the right.

You can toggle it in View -> Panes -> Details Pane:

[image: You can toggle it in View -> Panes -> Details Pane].

Once there, you can hover over any of the detais - Windows will highlight the editable ones - just click to edit.

Comment: thank you for replying I know what you mean but it's not what I am talking about. In the bottom panel that was showed in Windows7 I had the option to RENAME or give a nam/tag to details-while in Windows 10 I cannot .  I cannot be more clearer, sorry. Look at the screenshot posted in the post I have quoted please. Thanks again.